# Copy/Paste relative links between buffers

Tags: org-mode, copy-paste, org-link

How can I copy (relative) links and regions with (relative) links between buffers?

Buffer `c:\path\to\a\a.org` contains links of the form

```
* A section with links
This is a link to another org-file
[[file:../../b.org][A link]]
* This is a link to a picture
[[./pictures/pic.png]]
```

How do I copy a link (or a text block containing multiple links) and paste it to a file `c:\other\path\c.org` and keep the links working?

The expected behavior is to fix the paths in `c.org` so that the link points at the original file. Pasting into `c.org` would insert this:

```
* A section with links
This is a link to another org-file
[[file:../../path/b.org][A link]]
* This is a link to a picture
[[../../path/to/a/pictures/pic.png]]
```